# Is there a gui application for managing multiple mice/keyboards?

Tags: xorg, input-devices, multipointerx

I remember a few years ago seeing an application for Fedora that allowed you to manage multiple mice or keyboards as separate input devices (based on multipointerx technology).

With this application you were able to tell the system to use two pointers (for example if you have a mouse and a touchpad), and to handle them as separate devices instead of having the same settings (I think) for each.

Unfortunately this program never did compile/work for me when I tried it, and I do not remember the name (nor have I been able to find it since then).

Does anyone know what I'm referring to, or know of a program that does this?

*P.S. (I know how to use the `xinput` command already, so I don't want a commandline application as a suggestion).*

Comment: seems like they are making individual window managers just for this, like MPWM, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/lock-second-mouse-pointer-keyboard-input-to-one-window , not sure if it will work in ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 9.04 only

Roland, regarding your query Its *was* very much possible using a tool called

```
gnome-device-setup
```

I used it myself on 9.04

---

[image: http://bp0.blogger.com/_QPiOlFN2PF8/SHQ_MrOgVDI/AAAAAAAAAAU/07UeqCR4r7w/s320/gnome-device-setup.png]

You can see it in action
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nS06QjHlrwk&feature=related

Sadly, the links are broken
[http://people.freedesktop.org/~whot/gnome-device-setup](http://people.freedesktop.org/%7Ewhot/gnome-device-setup)

> This has been taken from http://who-t.blogspot.com/2008/07/gnome-device-setup.html

Comment: Maybe @StefanoPalazzo can make an implementation

Comment: I think there was another application, but this is what I'm looking for :). I wish it was still supported.

Comment: @RolandTaylor Badluck for you . I purged my 9.04 install last week :P

Comment: np... "bad luck" is nothing new to me.

Comment: @RolandTaylor FYI. Trying to run it on 10.10+ will break x and the cursor will be left unmovable.Although Keyboard works

Comment: Gnome Device Manager does the job too.

Answer (score 2):

the gnome-device-setup seems to me like a frontend to xinput. With these commands you are able to create more virtual pointers:

```
xinput list
xinput create-master <name>
xinput reattach <input-id> <pointer-id>  (id you can get from xinput list)
```

have fun.